# Dbt docs detailed section is empty when using custom schema

Tags: dbt

We are using custom schema :

profile.yml (specified db(with schema x ) and target as x)
defining schema in config section of each model (x for some models and y for some models), in macros used dbt provided code to overwrite the schema defined in models (https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas/)
when running the model
dbt run --m <model_name> (model is executing in schema defined in model)
Issue:in dbt docs details section is showing only for x schema but not to the schema y objects

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is more a bug report than a question. Maybe you could try reporting it to DBT directly

Comment: Add I assume that you also re-ran `dbt docs generate` ?